# Display images in a Webform options (that displays a likert scale)

Tags: webforms, 9

I'm looking for a way to display images in Webform options that I have created. The Webform options display a Likert scale with 4 options.

The machine name of the Webform option is 'qoli_simplified_scale.' I want to add a different image to each one of the options.

(The value numbers are a bit different than the 1 to 4 you would assume them to be.)
Option value 2 has the option text 'No, I disagree.'
Option value 3 has the option text 'Yes, I agree.'
Option value 7 has the option text 'I don't know.'
Option value 8 has the option text 'Not Important.'

The images I want to display are in the folder '/themes/custom/qoli/assets/questionnaire_images/'.

For option value 2, I want to display 'image10.png' from the folder above.
For option value 3, I want to display 'image6.png' from the folder above.
For option value 7, I want to display 'image14.png' from the folder above.
For option value 8, I want to display 'image13.png' from the folder above.

Currently, this Webform options displays only the text of each of the 4 options. I want to also add an image to each option along with the text.

**So, basically, how do I add an image to Webform options that display a Likert scale?**

I'm assuming that I have to utilize my custom theme's .theme file and add a hook there OR should I create a Webform custom options element?

I'd be grateful for any help I could get on this.